# Program won't start with XML Settings in certain situations

Tags: windows, xml

So I am trying to do something for my work (please let me know if there is an easier way to do this)

We have workers transferring images to a computer in our office.  They are generally way too big, so we found a program called "DropReSize" which allows you to create a folder that it will monitor and whenever a new image is put in that folder, it will automatically resize it for you.

The problem is this program crashes from time to time.

So I found a few other programs that monitor if an application has crashed or closed and will re-open them if so.

If I re-open DropReSize manually by double clicking in the folder, it re-opens fine with all of my settings loaded from a .xml file in the same directory.

However, when it is re-opened (by any of these monitoring applications including Windows Task manager) - it opens, but without the settings.  Even though I have it pointed to the same .exe in the same directory as the .xml - it will not load the settings with it.

Any idea why this is?  Or if you could think of an easier way to do what I am trying to do I would appreciate it.